Problem with SortedDictionary in C# 11 with .NET 4.8 / Globalization
A web site uses the current culture of the user for displaying data. A problem occured when a user from Vietnam accessed the data. Can someone explain why this problems occurs?
Code to reproduce the error:
static void SortedDicProblem(Action<string> Write)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    const string key = "KH";

    SortedDictionary<string, string> laCountries = new()
    {
        { key, "Kambodscha " },
        { "KI", "Kiribati " },
        { "KM", "Komoren " },
    };

    foreach (CultureInfo loCult in System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures))
    {
        Test(loCult.Name);
    }

    void Test(string vsCulture)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(vsCulture);

        if (laCountries.TryGetValue(key, out string lsName))
        {
            Write($"{vsCulture}");
        }
        else
        {
            Write($"<span class='error'>{vsCulture}, Key not found: {key}, {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.EnglishName}</span>");
        }
    }
}

We'll know how to solve it, but what's the reason for this error?
A Solution to avoid the problem: Instantiate the SortedDictionary with a StringComparer, like:
new SortedDictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)


And what is the error?

The error is that TryGetValue sometimes (depending on the culture) does not find the key "KH" in the SortedDictionary. It does not find "KH" for the cultures "vi" (Vietnam) and "haw" (Hawaian).

sometimes? not always?

"sometimes" reads "when a user with the culture 'vi' visits the page".

I can reproduce it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BCvXPU. Used AllCultures instead of InstalledWin32Cultures though, since otherwise .net fiddle doesn't have any cultures

Here is the issue (occurs on .NET 4.8, not on .NET 5+):
public static void Main()
{
    var usComparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("en-US"), ignoreCase: false);
    var veComparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("vi-VN"), ignoreCase: false);

    Console.WriteLine(usComparer.Compare("KH", "KM")); // Prints -1
    Console.WriteLine(veComparer.Compare("KH", "KM")); // Prints  1
}

In English-US, "KH" is considered to be before "KM".
In Vietnamese, "KH" is considered to be after "KM".
Because you have inserted the items into the dictionary using one comparer, and then tried to retrieve them using a different comparer which gives a different sort order, it all falls apart.
As to why it's different on .NET 5+ - well that's a different question. I would imagine that it's to do with the fact that .NET core uses ICU for string comparisons and .NET 4.8 uses NLS.

You can make the issue also occur on .NET 5+ by forcing the use of NLS rather than ICU by adding the following to the project file and recompiling:
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>


ADDENDUM
I couldn't work out why this was failing, given that the implementation of SortedDictionary caches the comparer. Surely it should give the same results even when you change the locale?
Well it turns out that Comparer<string>.Default actually changes its behaviour when you change locale, even if it's been cached!
Consider this code, which demonstrates:
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Default; // "Cache" the comparer.
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare("KH", "KM"));                  // Prints -1
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("vi-VN");
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Compare("KH", "KM"));                  // Prints 1

That explains why the search goes wrong even though the comparer was cached.
But what explains the behaviour of the cached comparer? It's quite simple. The cached comparer is of type GenericComparer<T>, the implementation of which is:
    public override int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x != null)
        {
            if (y != null) return x.CompareTo(y);
            return 1;
        }
        if (y != null) return -1;
        return 0;
    }

So since T is string, this is effectively just calling the string.CompareTo() method, which will be using the current locale.

Why does the sort order matter if he used TryGetValue?

@TimSchmelter Because the sort order determines the positioning of the keys in the SortedDictionary at insertion time and the finding of the keys at lookup time. (SortedDictionary is using a red-black tree as its implementation.)

You would get a similar problem if you sorted some strings in a simple array using one comparer and then tried to use a binary search to find a string in that array using a different comparer.

That's not a different comparer, the comparer never changes, what changes is the result of the comparison.

@shingo The comparer DOES change. From the documentation: if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic comparer Comparer<T>.Default is used. The Comparer<T>.Default is different for different thread locales, so when you change the thread locale, you are indirectly changing Comparer<T>.Default.

I am only aim at the question, as the comparer of the sorted dictionary is initialized in its constructor.

@MatthewWatson: i still don't get it(deleted my first comment). Even if the comparer used to find the key is different, the order should not matter, TryGetValue just needs to find out if two keys are equal, so Comparer.Compare returns 0. That should not change, does it? The string "KH" is contained even for those cultures where TryGetValue returns false

@TimSchmelter It's a SORTED dictionary, so the order does matter.

It's very hard to follow the code in the referencesource, so I can't fully explain why it appears to cache the comparer, but it still goes wrong. It could be that the .NET 4.8 version doesn't cache it.

I've worked out the full details now: Added to the answer.

Nice Addendum, now it's clear what's happening behind the scenes
